# Use preg_* to do time()

Tags: php, regex

I'm kinda stuck here, I made some preg coding to find any 11 digits numbers, but what I don't know how to make it use the found/matched to a function like "preg - time()"

Reminder, the 11 digits will might be found more than one time, so the function should be enable to be used on any of them, maybe a loop on a array or anything?

```
"#\d{11}#"   -   Quick example on the preg i might will use.
```

Help!

Comment: You are trying to find timestamps with regex? Where exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Unix timestamps have variable length. They could be anywhere from 0 to  1347912500 and beyond .. or -1347912500 to 0. There's no way to tell if a number came from time() or not because it's just an int.

Comment: I want to find all numbers with 11 digits, and do a function with them, example, minus the number with the current time

Comment: `if (is_int($time) && strlen($time) == 11)`.. but again, unix timestamps will not always have 11 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to use a custom function to make changes to each of the matches.

```
function your_custom_function($matches){
    $match = $matches[0];
    // Do something with $match
    return $match;
}
$string = preg_replace_callback(
    "#\d{11}#",
    "your_custom_function",
    $string
);
```

Comment: Wait, solved, another problem is that it stops to search for more than one, also, after the function, it stop entirely

Comment: @do0l67, you were matching `anything` followed by `whitespace`, so it thought it was one long link (see http://codepad.org/3mXAFqaw). Also, for YouTube links, you were checking against `$link` instead of `$link[0]`. Try something like this instead: http://codepad.org/IiaZlPIk

Comment: Well, i found out what makes it not apear, it's because it is using "#(http://)(.*\S)#, tried to replace yours with mine, in your 1st writen code, and that was the error, might help me rewrite it to // and not ##? EXTRA NOTE: I just saw your code, replaced it with the line, worked perfectly! I can also use this to identify users in the database! Thanks! Love this new thing, never thought about it!

Answer (score 0):

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) automatically replaces all, and [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) will give you all the matches in the third parameter.

```
preg_match("/\d{11}/", "Quick example on the preg I might will use", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```